# After Ubuntu update Apache2 is not working anymore

Tags: apache2, php7

After Ubuntu 14.04 weekly update (not version upgrade), `php7.0` apache module was updated. Since then `apache2` server is not working anymore.

Here's the error output:

```
Starting web server apache2                                                                                   
The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax 
error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load: Cannot load 
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so into server: 
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so: undefined symbol: 
ap_map_http_request_error
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

I guarantee that my apache conf and virtual hosts confs are ok!

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After run "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade", PHP 7.0 and PHP 7.1 apache modules were updated and the server came back to work!